# substitute for apache xml rpc client that is fully supported by google app engine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xml-rpc

I have a planned use of Apache XML RPC Client in a java web app on Google App Engine....I read somewhere that support for this client in App Engine is partial.

Is there some good substitute/equivalent java library that you can suggest, that is fully supported by Google App Engine for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTlet has a specific GAE edition

see http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/275-restlet/252-restlet.html